# Какой javascript фреймворк выбрать для интеграции в существующий проект использующий jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Посоветуйте, каким javascript-фреймворком воспользоваться для интеграции в существующий проект.

**Что имеем:**

Присутствует множество форм, которые динамически меняются исходя из выбранных параметров, выгружаются данные ajax запросом, валидация на клиенте, роутинг на клиенте итд итп.

Используется jQuery и немало тяжеловесных плагинов от которых в идеале нужно избавляться. Есть ряд решений с которыми jQuery справляется, но сопровождать и поддерживать проблематично.

Присутствует небольшой опыт работы с Ember, Angular.

**Проблема:**

Переводить полностью весь сайт на новый js фреймворк (сайт на клиенте) не выйдет, необходимо постепенно "причесать" отдельные элементы страниц с дальнейшими апгрейдом на полноценное клиентское приложение.

На мой взгляд Ember, Angular слишком тяжеловесные, прибавить к этому еще ряд плагинов от которых не сможем отказаться на начальном этапе, станет только хуже.

**Требуется:**

- Не громоздкий фреймворк поддерживающий ройтинг, модели, контроллеры,
  шаблоны, валидацию.
- Возможность создавать отдельные "компоненты" взаимодействия с формами и другими элементами на странице.